# python best way to create infinitive loop without a crash

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Cubieboard development board with Linux installed running a python program to turn various GPIO pins on and off when needed. One of those pins is listening out for a button press (which simple sends 0 volts to one of the pins setting it as a 'low' state). To do this I'm using the following code:

```
while 1:
    stopButton = wiringpi2.digitalRead(52)
    if (stopButton == 0)
         wiringpi2.digitalWrite(pin1,LOW) #this sets a pre defined pin to low or 0
```

This works just as expected, once the button is pressed the GPIO pin I've configured for pin1 is set to low or 0 value turning an LED off.

The problem comes if the button isn't pressed within roughly 30 seconds the programme crashes with the following error:

```
open /dev/mem faild.open /dev/mem failed.open /dev/mem failed.open /dev/mem failed.1
wiringPiSetUp: Unable to open /dev/mem: Too many open files
```

What would be a better way of writing the above code to prevent the crash?

Comment: This is a memory fill up resp. too many opened file pointers, you probably could try to `del stopButton` or some other `close`-method after the `if` statement to force the garbage collector to clean up. However, it could also be a race condition, so maybe a simple `sleep 0.1` after the `if`-statement could be one way to go. Don't forget to `from time import sleep`.

Comment: Is there something like a digitalclose?

Comment: can you perhaps post bit more of your code? Are you definitely in this loop when the crash occurs? are you setting the pinMode? Also did you call the setup function before your while loop?

Comment: have a look at this code http://pastebin.com/t7tWT0cg taken from here http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-wiringpi2-for-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-in-raspbian

Comment: It' shouldn't crash, it's clearly a bug in the "wiringpi2" library. But when I read the library code it's seem strange because "digitalRead" doesn't call "wiringPiSetUp"... Can you paste more of your code somewhere ?